# PHP Product vs Product comparison

Tags: php, comparison

This is my first question at stackoverflow.I want two pages website like this one http://geekaphone.com/ It compares products features.I want something similar to it.In which on first page we put product a keywords and product b keywords,So after it we will get the product details comparison

Thanks

Comment: What do you have right now ? Comparing data is not a difficult task .

Comment: And you forgot to state what your actual question is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a DB like mySql with tables products and product_features. You can use any framework and do your 2 page web app.